# Swift Unwanted Space in TableView Presented Modally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

A picture is worth thousand words in this case. I have a tableview present modally onclick from other view controller (with one navigation controller in between for the navigation bar, if that is important to you). Somehow there is some strange, (1) gray space at the top right under the navigation bar overlapping on top of the tableview, and (2)gray space near the bottom of the tableview right below the last cell with button, as shown in cap screen. I have completely no idea what that is.

I have another project which I use almost completely same setting for the tableview and these two gray bars do not occur. So I feel quite strange as to how that happen.

Can anyone enlighten me on this? I don't even know how to call these two gray bars here.

[image: Strange gray spaces near the bottom and end of the tableview presented modally]

If scroll to top, the two problematic areas appear a bit differently, please see can screen below. It feels like something due to a same problem which I don't know what it is.

[image]

Comment: seems like navigation bar & tableView header both. Try navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true in viewDidLoad()

Comment: Hi @Mel. Just tried, no difference...

Comment: you should update your question with code. Hard to tell by looking at pictures

Comment: i dont think codes are relevant here, except if you can tell what kind of codes / objects / elements are possibly giving rise to those gray bar alike? If we do not even know what codes / objects could give rise to a gray bar with shape like this what good does it do to look at the code?